# what is incorrect in sybase query

Tags: sybase

I have to add a `field1` in `table1` as new column, while this `field1` is already a primary key in `table2`. I have written below query:

```
alter table1 a
add field1 smallint,
default 5 not null
```

What's wrong in the above query? It's in sybase database.

Comment: the coma is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit wrong.
It should be:

```
alter table table1
add field1 smallint
default 5 not null
```

Check out the docs here:http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug354.htm